# How to properly read through the json records and get all the text values in php

Tags: php

Am working with json record below. I want to get all the **text** fields/values. when I try to display record,

This is what I got

```
{"message":"Cont050. "}{"message":"Contoso. "}{"message":"123. "}{"message":"Main. "}
{"message":"street. "}{"message":"Redmond,. "}{"message":"WA. "}{"message":"98052. "}
{"message":"987454-3210. "}{"message":"6\/10\/2019. "}{"message":"Sales. "}{"message":"Associate:. "}
{"message":"Paul. "}{"message":"1. "}{"message":"Cappuccino. "}{"message":"I. "}{"message":"BACON. "}
{"message":"&. "}{"message":"EGGS. "}{"message":"Sunny-side-up. "}{"message":"Tax. "}{"message":"Total. "}
{"message":"$220. "}{"message":"9.5. "}
```

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

what am expecting to get is to have all the text values ascribed to just a single message variable like below

```
{"message":"Cont050 Contoso 123 Main street Redmond, WA 98052 987454-3210 6/10/2019 Sales Associate: Paul 1 Cappuccino I BACON & EGGS Sunny-side-up Tax Total $220 9.5 "}
```

**Below is my coding efforts so far**

```
$spacing = " ";
$output = '
    {
        "language": "en",
        "textAngle": 0.0,
        "orientation": "Up",
        "regions": [{
                "boundingBox": "236,480,851,2269",
                "lines": [{
                        "boundingBox": "646,480,441,115",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "646,480,441,115",
                            "text": "Cont050"
                        }]
                    },

                    {
                        "boundingBox": "308,576,198,106",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "308,576,198,106",
                            "text": "Contoso"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "301,683,386,137",
                        "words": [{
                                "boundingBox": "301,683,80,75",
                                "text": "123"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "403,706,115,86",
                                "text": "Main"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "538,744,149,76",
                                "text": "street"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "293,792,521,125",
                        "words": [{
                                "boundingBox": "293,792,255,120",
                                "text": "Redmond,"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "564,849,77,66",
                                "text": "WA"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "661,859,153,58",
                                "text": "98052"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "278,1009,367,106",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "278,1009,367,106",
                            "text": "987454-3210"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "265,1231,257,92",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "265,1231,257,92",
                            "text": "6/10/2019"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "259,1352,596,92",
                        "words": [{
                                "boundingBox": "259,1352,155,73",
                                "text": "Sales"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "434,1368,275,76",
                                "text": "Associate:"
                            }, {
                                "boundingBox": "732,1380,123,63",
                                "text": "Paul"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "249,1587,18,69",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "249,1587,18,69",
                            "text": "1"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "326,1591,327,92",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "326,1591,327,92",
                            "text": "Cappuccino"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "236,1842,498,75",
                        "words": [{
                                "boundingBox": "236,1842,19,73",
                                "text": "I"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "315,1843,190,73",
                                "text": "BACON"
                            }, {
                                "boundingBox": "529,1847,39,69",
                                "text": "&"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "593,1847,141,70",
                                "text": "EGGS"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "boundingBox": "350,1978,393,82",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "350,1978,393,82",
                            "text": "Sunny-side-up"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "445,2371,113,88",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "445,2371,113,88",
                            "text": "Tax"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "437,2644,166,105",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "437,2644,166,105",
                            "text": "Total"
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "boundingBox": "1113,1580,153,465",
                "lines": [{
                    "boundingBox": "1113,1580,153,84",
                    "words": [{
                        "boundingBox": "1113,1580,153,84",
                        "text": "$220"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "boundingBox": "1139,1954,122,91",
                    "words": [{
                        "boundingBox": "1139,1954,122,91",
                        "text": "9.5"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ],
        "modelVersion": "2021-04-01"
    }
    ';

$json = json_decode($output, true);

foreach ($json['regions'] as $row1) {
    //echo  $boundingBox = $row1['boundingBox'];
    foreach ($row1['lines'] as $row2) {
        //echo  $boundingBox = $row2['boundingBox'];
        foreach ($row2['words'] as $row3) {
            $words = $row3['text'];
            $extracts = "$words.$spacing";
            $output_response = array(
                "message" => $extracts);
            echo json_encode($output_response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. If you have multiple objects, they need to be in an array: `[]` around the whole thing, and `,` between each object.

Comment: That is the response or output that I got from Azure OCR API call

Comment: Sir, I can send you the API call code to inspect

Comment: If `$output` is what you're working with, that's OK.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated  Sir @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't echo a new JSON object each time through the loop. Put the text in an array, then use `implode()` at the end to combine them into a single string, and put that in a single JSON object.

```
$message = [];

foreach ($json['regions'] as $row1) {
    //echo  $boundingBox = $row1['boundingBox'];
    foreach ($row1['lines'] as $row2) {
        //echo  $boundingBox = $row2['boundingBox'];
        foreach ($row2['words'] as $row3) {
            $message[] = $row3['text'];
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode(['message' => implode(' ', $message)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$spacing = " ";
$output = '
    {
        "language": "en",
        "textAngle": 0.0,
        "orientation": "Up",
        "regions": [{
                "boundingBox": "236,480,851,2269",
                "lines": [{
                        "boundingBox": "646,480,441,115",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "646,480,441,115",
                            "text": "Cont050"
                        }]
                    },

                    {
                        "boundingBox": "308,576,198,106",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "308,576,198,106",
                            "text": "Contoso"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "301,683,386,137",
                        "words": [{
                                "boundingBox": "301,683,80,75",
                                "text": "123"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "403,706,115,86",
                                "text": "Main"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "538,744,149,76",
                                "text": "street"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "293,792,521,125",
                        "words": [{
                                "boundingBox": "293,792,255,120",
                                "text": "Redmond,"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "564,849,77,66",
                                "text": "WA"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "661,859,153,58",
                                "text": "98052"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "278,1009,367,106",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "278,1009,367,106",
                            "text": "987454-3210"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "265,1231,257,92",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "265,1231,257,92",
                            "text": "6/10/2019"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "259,1352,596,92",
                        "words": [{
                                "boundingBox": "259,1352,155,73",
                                "text": "Sales"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "434,1368,275,76",
                                "text": "Associate:"
                            }, {
                                "boundingBox": "732,1380,123,63",
                                "text": "Paul"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "249,1587,18,69",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "249,1587,18,69",
                            "text": "1"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "326,1591,327,92",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "326,1591,327,92",
                            "text": "Cappuccino"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "236,1842,498,75",
                        "words": [{
                                "boundingBox": "236,1842,19,73",
                                "text": "I"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "315,1843,190,73",
                                "text": "BACON"
                            }, {
                                "boundingBox": "529,1847,39,69",
                                "text": "&"
                            },
                            {
                                "boundingBox": "593,1847,141,70",
                                "text": "EGGS"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "boundingBox": "350,1978,393,82",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "350,1978,393,82",
                            "text": "Sunny-side-up"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "445,2371,113,88",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "445,2371,113,88",
                            "text": "Tax"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "437,2644,166,105",
                        "words": [{
                            "boundingBox": "437,2644,166,105",
                            "text": "Total"
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "boundingBox": "1113,1580,153,465",
                "lines": [{
                    "boundingBox": "1113,1580,153,84",
                    "words": [{
                        "boundingBox": "1113,1580,153,84",
                        "text": "$220"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "boundingBox": "1139,1954,122,91",
                    "words": [{
                        "boundingBox": "1139,1954,122,91",
                        "text": "9.5"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ],
        "modelVersion": "2021-04-01"
    }
    ';

$json = json_decode($output, true);
$text = "";
foreach ($json['regions'] as $row1) {
    //echo  $boundingBox = $row1['boundingBox'];
    foreach ($row1['lines'] as $row2) {
        //echo  $boundingBox = $row2['boundingBox'];
        foreach ($row2['words'] as $row3) {
            $words = $row3['text'];
            $extracts = "$words$spacing";   // already spacing
            $text.= $extracts;
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode(array("message" => $text));
```

Explaination:
$extracts is combine of $words and $spacing (defined on top)
Put extract to some temporary variable
After all info gathered, echo with json_encode

Answer (score 1):

```
$output_response = array('message' => "");

$json = json_decode($output, true);
foreach ($json['regions'] as $row1) {
    foreach ($row1['lines'] as $row2) {
        foreach ($row2['words'] as $row3) {
            $output_response['message'] .= $row3['text']." ";
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($output_response);
```